# Сan’t get a SAML response from ADFS server

Tags: java, spring, saml, adfs

We have ADFS server (windows server 2012 R2).
Need to add authorization in custom application (lib spring-security-saml2-core).

Authentication steps:

1) create SAML AuthRequest and send to ADFS server

2) User is automatically redirected to the login page of the server, enters the correct credentials

3) No response from server. Error in log:

```
The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the SAML authentication request.
```

Additional Data 
Exception details:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = Microsoft.IdentityServer.Tokens.MSISSecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
'. Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.ResolveSigningCredentials()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.OnEndOfRootElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadAuthnRequest(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String encodedSamlMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
```

Can anyone help with this error?
 How to get a response?

We use this article to configure certificates and jks file: https://docs.microfocus.com/SM/9.61/Hybrid/Content/security/tasks/configure_saml_setup_relationship_between_idm_adfs.htm

Security XML:

```
   <!-- ADFS filter -->
   <bean id="adfsAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
      class="com.webapp.filter.ADFSAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlAuthenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="logAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sessionFixationProtectionStrategy"/>
    <property name="SAMLProcessor" ref="processor"/>
    <property name="contextProvider" ref="contextProvider"/>
    <property name="userManager" ref="userManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="entityId"
                      value="http://{ADFS server}/adfs/services/trust"/>
            <property name="requestSigned" value="false"/>
            <property name="extendedMetadata">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="manager" ref="metadata"/>
</bean>


<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg name="metadata" type="java.io.File"
                                         value="/WEB-INF/saml/sp_metadata.xml"/>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="local" value="true"/>
                        <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="keyName"/>
                        <property name="encryptionKey" value="keyName"/>
                        <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="true"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="true"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="true"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="requireValidMetadata" value="false"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg name="metadata" type="java.io.File"
                                         value="/WEB-INF/saml/ip_metadata.xml"/>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="local" value="false"/>
                        <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="keyName"/>
                        <property name="encryptionKey" value="keyName"/>
                        <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="requireValidMetadata" value="false"/>
            </bean>

        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager"/>
    <property name="TLSConfigurer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
            <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager"/>
            <property name="trustedKeys">
                <set>

                </set>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="hostedSPName"
              value="http://{ADFS server}/adfs/services/trust"/>
    <property name="defaultIDP"
              value="http://{ADFS server}/adfs/services/trust"/>
</bean>

<bean id="logAuthenticationSuccessHandler" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.webapp.security.login.LogAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/startPage.htm"/>
            <property name="requestCache" ref="savedRequestCache"/>
            <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
            <property name="attemptsManager" ref="authenticationAttemptsManager"/>
            <property name="userManager" ref="userManager"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="onAuthenticationSuccess">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--  SAML 2.0 -->
<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->

<sec:http pattern="/saml/**" entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <sec:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false" pattern="/">
    <sec:csrf/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <sec:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</sec:http>

<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
</bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
<bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error/403.jsf"/>
</bean>

<!-- Handler for successful logout -->
<bean id="successLogoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout"/>
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="samlAuthenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <sec:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/saml/samlKeystore.jks"/>

    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="123456"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="keyName" value="1234567"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="keyName"/>
</bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            <property name="nameID"
                      value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"/>
            <property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
            <property name="allowCreate" value="true"/>
            <property name="assertionConsumerIndex" value="0"/>
            <property name="passive" value="false"/>
            <property name="relayState"
                      value="https://{application URL}/saml/SSO/login.htm"/>
            <property name="forceAuthN" value="true"/>
            <property name="authnContexts">
                <list>
                    <value>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
                    </value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="samlLogger" ref="samlLogger"/>
    <property name="webSSOprofile" ref="webSSOprofile"/>
    <property name="contextProvider" ref="contextProvider"/>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login.htm"/>
</bean>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
<bean id="metadataDisplayFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter">
    <property name="manager" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="contextProvider" ref="contextProvider"/>
    <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">

    <property name="userDetails" ref="userDetails"/>
    <property name="consumer" ref="webSSOprofileConsumer"/>
    <property name="hokConsumer" ref="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer"/>
    <property name="samlLogger" ref="samlLogger"/>
    <property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetails" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.webapp.security.SAMLUserDetails">
            <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<bean id="contextProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl">
    <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager"/>
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
</bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlAuthenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="contextProvider" ref="contextProvider"/>
    <property name="SAMLProcessor" ref="processor"/>
</bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlAuthenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="contextProvider" ref="contextProvider"/>
    <property name="SAMLProcessor" ref="processor"/>
</bean>

<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<bean id="logoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!--Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!--First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
<bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <property name="SAMLProcessor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
    <property name="contextProvider" ref="contextProvider"/>
    <property name="logoutProfile" ref="logoutProfile"/>
    <property name="samlLogger" ref="samlLogger"/>
</bean>

<bean id="logoutProfile"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl">
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
</bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <ref bean="postBinding"/>
            <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
            <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
            <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl">
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>

    <property name="responseSkew" value="600"/>
    <property name="maxAuthenticationAge" value="7200"/>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl">
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="webSSOprofile" class="com.webapp.filter.CustomWebSSOProfileImpl">
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
    <!-- property name="metadataIssuerUrl" value="https://{ADFS server}/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" / -->
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOProfile"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl">
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl">
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
<bean id="logoutprofile"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl">
    <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
    <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
    <property name="responseSkew" value="600"/> 
</bean>

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redirectBinding"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="artifactBinding"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="processor" ref="samlProcessor"/>
            <property name="metadata" ref="metadata"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="samlProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpPostBinding"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpRedirectBinding"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpPostBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlHttpPostBinding"
      class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml1.binding.decoding.HTTPPostDecoder">
            <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.webapp.filter.HttpRedirectDeflateAsHttpPostEncoder"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory"
      factory-method="getEngine"/>

<bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool"
      init-method="initialize"/>

<bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
```

SAML AuthRequest:

```
  <!-- ADFS filter -->
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <saml2p:AuthnRequest
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://{application URL}/saml/SSO/login.htm"
Destination="https://{ADFS server}/adfs/ls/" ForceAuthn="true"
ID="ID" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2019-08-28T07:36:16.121Z"
ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0"
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://{ADFS server URL}/adfs/services/trust</saml2:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#ID">
            <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>pA3hIQrobfvJmjpV76SuMhfD5Ig=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>...==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature><saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"
    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"/>
<saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
    <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
</saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

Comment: It could be that your ADFS server only accepts signature algorithm 'SHA256' instead of 'SHA1' or it could be that you have not provided /configured the certificate of the SAML SP (Spring Security SAML extension based one) to your ADFS server.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on a project where we set up KeyCloak to act as an SP to ADFS IdP.

We were only able to get the SAML requests to process correctly when the following settings were set:

---

IdP URL: `${IDP_URL}/adfs/ls/`

NameID Policy Format: `persistent`

WantAuthnRequestsSigned: `true`

WantAssertionsSigned: `true`

SignatureAlgorithm: `RSA_SHA256`

SAMLSignatureKeyName: `CERT_SUBJECT`

---

In addition to updating the NameID Policy on our side (as SP), we also had to have custom settings on the IdP side to ensure the NameID was sent back as format `persistent`.

I see from your authn request that the NameID Policy is currently set to `emailAddress`.